# Unity Referencing an Instantiated (cloned) object on a Button via Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My Problem:
I cant get it to work, that every Building has its own SpawnPoint.

I'm working on an RTS like build mechanism. I have set it up that after pressing a key I can place buildings in the scene. The buildings get instantiated from a prefab and after they get instantiated they get a script called "BuildingScript" attached to them. Now i want to implement, so that i get a individual spawn point for every building (for now just next to it). I got a UI set up with a button, which by pressing spawns a unit at the building.

I had the "BuildingScript" attached to the prefab, but when i set the spawn point for one Building, it set it for every Building in the Scene. So a Unit was Spawned always at the same Buidling.
I want to set it up, that every Building has its own spawn point. Thats why I want to give every Building the script "BuildingScript" when Instatiated, because I hope, that this way every script gets handled individually. Is that right? Or will it still set the same point for every building, because the script is still the same?

Also I wanna reference the current placed building to the button, so when its clicked, it will run only the code of the last placed building (for now). I think I cant do this by using "On Click()" Of the Button, because my clone isnt Instatiated yet, so I have to reference the clone to the button somehow via Script, so the button works with the clone.So my problem is, that I need to set a reference from my cloned Building to the Button, after I placed the clone.
I googled a lot on how to do this, but didnt found any answers to my problem besides this https://forum.unity.com/threads/controlling-instantiated-game-objects-from-ui-buttons.332005/.

But I cant get it to work and I think it will not work because my clone is an Object and not a GameObject, so I could never set reference to it to call the funktion SpawnUnit(), because GetComponent only works for a GameObject.

Now I'm really at a point where I just don't know how Unity handles these kind of things.

BuildingScript on the Instantiated Building

```
public class BuildingScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool SavePos = false;

    public Vector3 SpawnPoint;
    public Vector3 BuildingPos;
    public GameObject Unit;    

    void Start()
    {
        FindObjectOfType<SpawnButtonReference>().GiveReference(this);
    }    

    public void SpawnUnit()
    {

//I did this because if a building gets instatiated i wanted it to save its 
Position to Spawn Units from it (doesnt really work though).
"MousePos" ist the last Position of the Mouse in the PlacementScript, before klicking to place the building.

        if (SavePos == false)
        {
            BuildingPos = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<GroundPlacementController>().GetComponent<GroundPlacementController>().MousePos;
            Debug.Log(BuildingPos);

            SavePos = true;
        }

        float PosX = BuildingPos.x + 2;
        float PosZ = BuildingPos.z + 2;
        SpawnPoint = new Vector3(PosX, 0, PosZ);
        Debug.Log("Spawn" + SpawnPoint);

        Instantiate(Unit, SpawnPoint, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Script on the Button

```
public class SpawnButtonReference : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objectReference = null;

    internal void GiveReference(BuildingScript Object)
    {
        objectReference = Object;
    }

    void OnButtonPress()
    {
        if (objectReference != null)
        {
            objectReference.GetComponent<BuildingScript>().SpawnUnit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't add "solved" or similar phrases to your question when you've solved the problem. If someone gave you an answer, [accept it](/help/someone-answers). If you found a solution on your own, [post an answer](/help/self-answer) (you can also accept your own answer after two days). Accepting answers is also the way to show a question has been solved - editing "solved" into the question is not.

Comment: ok didnt know that sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it myself with a little workaround. Instead of trying to reference the clone, I wrote a script on the Spawn Button which searches all Objects with the "BildingScript" then if they are Selected (which can only be one Building) it spawns a Unit at its Spawn point.
The Building itself saves his spawn point when being placed (so when Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))

works very well for me :)